# R rearranging columns in dplyr using indices

Tags: r, select, dplyr

I like using `dplyr`, especially the chaining functionality.
I'm struggling to figure out the how to use `dplyr` to rearrange the columns in a data frame using column index. Using column names is OK in a small data frame but a pain when there are lots of columns.

Take some data:

```
data <- head(iris)
colnames(data)
[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species" 

#rearrange to: "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species" "Sepal.Length"

#using indices with base r
> colnames(data[,c(2:5,1)])
[1] "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"      "Sepal.Length"

#using names with dplyr
colnames(select(iris, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Species, Sepal.Length))
[1] "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"      "Sepal.Length"
```

Can someone enlighten me how to use indices with `dplyr` `select`?

Comment: Have you tried `select(iris, c(2:5,1))`? Or just `select(iris, 2:5, 1)`

Comment: @docendodiscimus well that's embarrassing. Sure I tried that.... although I think when I did try it I used `[2:5], [1]`. Thanks. Will accept it as an answer if you can be bothered to write it up

Comment: You can post it yourself as an answer if you like